# When you use 'Rebound' does the card go to the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Someone suggested I read the basic guide of mtg because I'm new to the game, so I was reading it and [on page 7 (Game Zones) where it talks about Exile](http://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/en_magic_basic_rulebook_20090710.pdf) it says:

> If a spell or ability exiles a card, that card is put in a game area that's set apart from the rest of the game. The card will remain there forever, unless whatever put it there is able to bring it back. Exiled cards are normally face up. This zone is shared by both players.

So if you played a card like [Staggershock](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Staggershock) and next turn you use rebound, spell happens, does it remain in exile or go to the graveyard?

(Also, not a question but a side note, all players share the same exile? Thats interesting I didn't know that till just now.)

Comment: If you really want to know more about your side note (a single exile zone) you should probably ask a separate question.

Comment: @Jefromi I wasn't trying to ask a question about the single exile I was just saying it was something sorta interesting on the same part of the rules I was reading, sorry.

Comment: Re "All players share the same exile?", There's only one Battlefield, Stack and Exile zone. Each player has a Library, Hand, Graveyard and Commander zone.

Comment: @ikegami I guess I did say it as a question, I guess in my head is was like when someone tells you something and you say 'Really? That's interesting', sorry for the confusion I'll try not to do it in future questions, thanks for you're help everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *does it remain in exile or go to the graveyard?*

Neither. It's moved to the stack when you cast it. From there, it will go to the graveyard on resolution (or upon being countered) as normal.

---

If you exercise the option to Rebound a previously-exiled Staggershock, you cast Staggershock. The first step of casting a spell is to move the card from the zone in which it's located (usually your hand, but exile in this case) to the stack.

> 601.2a The player announces that he or she is casting the spell. That card (or that copy of a card) moves from where it is to the stack. [...]

At that point, it leaves exile. This is that to which "unless whatever put it there is able to bring it back" refers.

When the spell resolves, it will then go from the stack to the graveyard as normal since it was cast from exile rather than your hand.

> 702.87a Rebound appears on some instants and sorceries. It represents a static ability that functions while the spell is on the stack and may create a delayed triggered ability. “Rebound” means “**If this spell was cast from your hand**, instead of putting it into your graveyard as it resolves, exile it and, at the beginning of your next upkeep, you may cast this card from exile without paying its mana cost.”
>
> 608.2k As the final part of an instant or sorcery spell’s resolution, the spell is put into its owner’s graveyard. [...]

Answer (score 3):

When you cast the spell a second time off rebound (from exile), it ends up in your graveyard. This is actually one of the Gatherer rulings on [Staggershock](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Staggershock):

> If you cast a card from exile this way, it will go to your graveyard when it resolves or is countered. It won't go back to exile.

If you have a closer look at the reminder text (emphasis added):

> Rebound *(**If you cast this spell from your hand**, exile it as it resolves. At the beginning of your next upkeep, you may cast this card from exile without paying its mana cost.)*

You only exile it as it resolves when you cast it from your hand. Any other time, like when you're casting it the second time (from exile) you follow the normal process for casting a spell, including putting it into your graveyard as it resolves.

Reminder text isn't actually the full binding rules, but it's generally accurate and in this case it's only very slightly different from the full rules:

> If this spell was cast from your hand, instead of putting it into your graveyard as it resolves, exile it and, at the beginning of your next upkeep, you may cast this card from exile without paying its mana cost.